# How to change font in suggestions of an AutocompleteTextview?

Tags: android, fonts, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview, typeface

I'm trying to change the font of the suggestions of an AutocompleteTextView, created through the ArrayAdapter

```
Wadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
```

I looked for the file simple_dropdown_item_1line.xml and transfered it to my layout folder. Here is its content:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

This makes it easy to change, for example, the size of the suggestions. But the font type cannot be changed from the xml (except for basic font options), this needs to be done from code. I tried to use this lines of code:

```
TextView scroll= (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Typewriter.ttf");
scroll.setTypeface(type);
```

but the last line gives me NullPointerException. Anybody has an idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Which line throws the `NPE`?

Comment: the last one, that is the textview seems to be null...

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom adapter, and assign a new font to suggestions there.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private final Typeface tf;

    public AddContactAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<String> data, String FONT) {
        super(context, layout, contacts);
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

        TextView suggestion = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        suggestion.setText(getItem(position).toString());
        suggestion.setTypeface(tf);

        return rowView;
    }
```

And then assign your custom adapter in your Activity like this:

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, data, "path to font");
```

Comment: where can I put these code? can I put it in fragment class?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that `Typewriter.ttf` is the right filename of your font, and that it's added to `assets` folder.

**EDIT**

You may try also changing the `TextView id` to

```
android:id="@+id/text1"
```

and get the view with

```
TextView scroll = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

Comment: No problem with that, I already use the same font everywhere else in my app and works with no problems. I just can't figure out how to use it in this case!

Comment: I did it, no errors in code but still NPE at execution at the same line!

Comment: Just to make sure, debug and evaluate `scroll` and `type` variables. Let's see which one is null.

Comment: type is not null, I use it in the sequel of the code to change the font of buttons and textviews with the command setTypeface, and that creates no problem.

Comment: Mmh I'm running out of bullets here... Are you sure you're setting the right layout xml for the content view of that activity?

Comment: to resume: the textview above is in the file simple_dropdown_item_1line.xml, in layout folder. The content view is in another xml in the same folder.

Comment: And you're doing `include` of the textview's xml inside the content xml, aren't you?

Comment: No I'm not! How should I do it to be sure that it does not appear in the app graphical layout but is just a template for suggestions?

Comment: If you don't include it, sure you'll have a NullPointerException. For 'template for suggestions', you mean leave the code as a guide so that you can easily copy&paste? You could just put it between comment tags `<!-- -->`, but then make sure you just setTypeface if `scroll != null`

Comment: the textview is in simple_dropdown_item_1line.xml, which is called by the Arrayadapter to create the shape of the suggestions when needed (using the textview as a sort of 'template'). I don't get why I should put the textview in the content view together with all the other stuff appearing directly at the start of the app...