# How do I change the font of Android AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Shockingly there doesn't seem to be any questions that successfully answer this. I am trying to change the font in the AutoCompleteTextView. How can I accomplish this? I'm assuming this would involve creating a custom class that extends AutoCompleteTextView but how would I do this specifically?

[image]

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199115/how-to-change-font-in-suggestions-of-an-autocompletetextview?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an Adapter and use the setAdapter(...) method to apply it.  Adapters are used to serve up and cache views for efficient scrolling in Android.  The AutoCompleteTextView will call the getView(...) method on your Adapter giving it the position that it wants.  You create or modify a view with the content at that position (in this case the text) and return it.

Here's a good example article of it:
http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/12/android-autocompletetextview-custom-arrayadapter-sqlite.html

You might just want to scroll to the adapter part.

Answer (score 1):

You are showing the drop-down list. You control the font yourself when your code creates your rows in your `Adapter` implementation used for suggestions. Override `getView()` and adjust the font in your `TextViews` in the row layout.